# Filtering the options of ModelChoiceField in forms in django as per the ForeignKey relations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In my django project, I created three model classes. The class 'Subtopic' has ForeignKey relation with class 'Chapter' and class 'SAQ' has ForeignKey relation with class 'Chapter' and class 'Subtopic'.

```
#models.py

from django.db import models
class Chapter(models.Model):
    chapter_serial = models.IntegerField(null=False, help_text="Chapter No.")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    chapter_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["chapter_serial"]

    def get_saq_list_url(self):
        return reverse("cms:saq_list", kwargs={"chap_slug":self.slug})

class Subtopic(models.Model):
    subtopic_serial = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey('Chapter', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["subtopic_serial"]

class SAQ(models.Model):
    question_serial = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    question = models.TextField()
    answer = models.TextField()
    chapter = models.ForeignKey('Chapter', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subtopic = models.ForeignKey('Subtopic', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["question_serial"]
```

I tried to create forms using django ModelForm for 'model SAQ' such that for each 'SAQ form' associated with a particular chapter instance, the choice field for model 'Subtopic' will contain only those subtopics of that particular chapter instance.

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import SAQ

class SAQForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SAQ
        fields = [
            'question_serial',
            'question',
            'answer',
            'important',
            'remarks',
            'subtopic',
        ]
```

The django view function to create the form is as below.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .models import SAQ, Chapter, Subtopic
from .forms import SAQForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def saq_create(request, chap_slug=None):
    chapter_instance = get_object_or_404(Chapter, slug=chap_slug)
    form = SAQForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.chapter = chapter_instance
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(chapter_instance.get_saq_list_url())
    context = {
        "form":form,
        "chapter_instance":chapter_instance,
    }
    return render(request, 'cms/saq_form.html', context)
```

With this configuration, the choice field in the form, for 'Subtopic' shows all subtopics for all chapter instances. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to override the form init and pass the chapter instance so you can filter the subtopic queryset.

Example (not tested, could contain typos):

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import SAQ

class SAQForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = SAQ
        fields = [
            'question_serial',
            'question',
            'answer',
            'important',
            'remarks',
            'subtopic',
        ]

    def __init__(self, chapter, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['subtopic'].queryset = \
            self.fields['subtopic'].queryset.filter(chapter=chapter)
```

And then your view should pass the chapter instance to the form:

```
chapter_instance = get_object_or_404(Chapter, slug=chap_slug)
form = SAQForm(chapter_instance, request.POST or None)
```